# Viewing Time using the Infragistics UltraDateTimeEditor for WinForms

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, infragistics

By default the UltraDateTimeEditor displays just the date.  What setting do I change to display/set the time in addition to the date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `MaskInput` Property should have a value like `{LOC}mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt`.

Documentation links:

- [Using the MaskInput
  Property](http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Support/KnowledgeBaseArticle.Aspx?ArticleID=2333)
- [MaskInput
  Property](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/infragistics2.Win.UltraWinEditors.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors.UltraDateTimeEditor~MaskInput.html)

Comment: The Help Page link is broken.

Comment: @VBNight {LOC}mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt  here "mm" refers both month and minute? can you Explain